# Caching after GAE standard migration to Go 1.11/1.12

Tags: google-app-engine

I've almost completed migrating based on [google's instructions.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences)

It's very nice to not have to call into the app-engine libraries whatsoever.

However, now I must replace my calls to app-engine-standard memcached.

Here's what the guide says:  "To use a memcache service on App Engine, use Redis Labs Memcached Cloud instead of App Engine Memcache."

So is this my only option; a third party?  They don't even list pricing on their page if GCE is selected.

I also see in the standard environment how-to guides there is a guide on [Connecting to internal resources in a VPC network.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/connecting-vpc)

From that link it mentions Cloud Memorystore.  I can't find any examples if this is advisable or possible to do on GAE standard.  Of course it wasn't previously possible but now that GAE standard has become much more "standard", I think it should be possible?

Thanks for any advice on the best way forward.

Comment: It's been a few months, what did you do?

Comment: Currently getting away without caching, hoping volume stays low enough until I have time to address this (early stages of ramping up).  My plan is to delay long enough for google to come up with something!  Or install bitnami redis or some other go based solution on a vm.  GAE standard is super open now so actually pretty easy to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memorystore appears to be Google's replacement:
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/

You connect to it using this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/using-memorystore

Alas it costs about $1.20/GB per day with no free quota.

Thus, if your data doesn't change, and requires less than 100MB of cache at a time, the first answer might be better (free). Also, your data won't explode the instance as you can control the max size of the cache.

However, if your data changes or you need more cache, MemoryStore is a more direct replacement to MemCache - just costs money.

Comment: This reflects the answer I got from Google back in May.  Perhaps out of "alpha" by now?
Google:
"3. Cloud Memorystore is a fully-managed Google service that provides fast, in-memory data store [7]. To use this product with App Engine standard it is required to use a VPC network connector which is currently in beta release [8][9]. At this time the VPC connector and App Engine must be in the same region and the only region that VPC connector can be used is us-central1. There is a Go client library available but it is currently in alpha so it is not stable and is likely to change [10]."

Comment: Finally an official guide.  This seems to be the correct answer now! 
 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/using-memorystore  (could edit your answer to include this link rather than connecting-vpc?)

Comment: "$1.20/GB per day with no free quota." Do they actually charge by the GB (with 1GB minimum), or would I be charged less than that if I only used 100MB in total?

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this. 2nd gen instances have twice the ram, so if global cache isn't required (as in items don't change once created - (name items using their sha256)), you can run your own local threadsafe memcache (such as https://github.com/dgraph-io/ristretto) and allocate some of the extra ram to it. It'll be faster than Memcache was, so requests can be serviced even faster, keeping the number of instances low.
You could make it global for data that does change, by using pub/sub between instances, but I think that's significantly more work.

Comment: So are you thinking this is per instance?  I guess it could work well with reasonably steady traffic, otherwise I guess you'd be losing out if instances were being created and shutdown regularly, since data wouldn't persist in those cases?

Comment: A cron job running every couple of minutes will keep one instance and it's cache alive. But if you need the Cron you're probably not getting enough traffic to go beyond the free query limit anyway.

However, with lots of high load sporadic traffic this is still a serious win in reducing queries.

Comment: If this answer is not acceptable, can you advise what you are looking for?

Comment: I think it's a very interesting answer and I appreciate it.  At scale I can see having a lot of data in the cache which would explode the instance.  Also, it seems to me that one of the selling points and principals of app engine standard is supposed to be fast scaling up and down, reliant on stateless service design.  So this kind of violates that.  I guess the answer I want needs to be scalable the way memorystore or redis would be.

Answer (score 0):

To ease the migration to 1.12, I have been thinking of using this solution:

1. create a dedicated app using the 1.11 runtime.
2. setup [twirp](https://twitchtv.github.io/twirp/docs/intro.html) endpoints to act as a proxy for all the deprecated app engine services (memcache, mail, search...)